# jQuery .show() multiple tags with the same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, show

I have my jQuery code setup so when a span is clicked, the

is hidden and an input box is shown it its place. From here the input box can be typed in and the value is passed back to the

.

My problem is that if I have multiple spans with the same name, only the first span will hide and show the input and I want all the spans with the same name to show.

The name of the spans are generated dynamically from a php for loop (title_$i where $i is the array key), so I am unable to manually rename each span.

My HTML table:

```
<table id="blank">
<tbody>
    <tr id="1" class="edit_tr" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td class="edit_td">
 <span id="title_1" class="text"><p>Bed 1</p></span>

            <input type="text" value="Bed 1" name="floor_room[1][]" class="editbox" id="title_input_1" style="display: none;">
        </td>
        <td class="edit_td">
 <span id="title_1" class="text"><p>Bed 2</p></span>

            <input type="text" value="Bed 2" name="floor_room[1][]" class="editbox" id="title_input_1" style="display: none;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="edit_tr" bgcolor="#f2f2f2">
        <td class="edit_td">
 <span id="title_2" class="text"><p>Bath</p></span>

            <input type="text" value="Bath" name="floor_room[2][]" class="editbox" id="title_input_2" style="display: none;">
        </td>
        <td class="edit_td">
 <span id="title_2" class="text"><p>Bed 1</p></span>

            <input type="text" value="Bed 1" name="floor_room[2][]" class="editbox" id="title_input_2" style="display: none;">
        </td>
        <td class="edit_td">
 <span id="title_2" class="text"><p>Bed 2</p></span>

            <input type="text" value="Bed 2" name="floor_room[2][]" class="editbox" id="title_input_2" style="display: none;">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".editbox").hide();
$(".text").show();
$(".edit_tr").click(function () {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#title_" + ID).hide();
    $("#title_input_" + ID).show();


}).change(function () {

    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $("#title_input_" + ID).val();


    $("#title_" + ID).html(title);


});

// Edit input box click action
$(".editbox").mouseup(function () {
    return false
});

// Outside click action
$(document).mouseup(function () {
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".text").show();
});
```

and working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8resbu2c/

Comment: You cannot have multiple HTML elements with the same ID. Use classes instead if they must be the same.

Comment: Its cheating & against html rules .It states : NO 2 ELEMENTS SHOULD HAVE SAME ID !!!

Comment: You want ALL spans with name = YOUR_NAME to show at a time , And now in ur code only 1 is showing correct?

Comment: Your fiddle is very nice , whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't give same Id to more than one element in a single view. If you need to give same name to more than one element. Its better to provide them the same class name to identify.

Comment: It should be a comment

Comment: comment privilege not yet earned ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('name=["floor_room[1][]"]').show();
```

use name selector of dom.